# when minimize browser's window, tooltipster's position not the same as has been set

Tags: tooltipster

I use tooltipster library.
I set tooltipster's position to be bottom. When I minimize the browser's window the tooltip is floating above, it's like the position was set to top.

How could I solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide some HTML + CSS to demonstrate the issue? jsfiddle?

Comment: The html is: <div id="my-tooltip"> 
        This div has a tooltip with HTML when you hover over it!
    </div> and script is :  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
                content: $('<span><strong>This text is in bold case !</strong></span>'),
    position : 'bottom',
            });
        });  So if you try to minimize the browser window in a such way that the tooltipster would not be entirely visible, than the tooltipster will have the position top, when it should be on bottom

Comment: I working jsfiddle would be a better approach here really. so that you can propely demonstrate the issue before any assumptions are made

Comment: Try to minimize the result window like I mentioned above https://jsfiddle.net/mnk01/5Cw4H/56/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the author's documented feedback, this functionality has been written but it not officially released yet.

This specific functionality has been requested and he has explained how it is implemented within the plugin options.

instead of:

```
...
position: 'bottom'
...
```

you put it in an array:

```
...
position: ['bottom']
...
```

this is how the scripts tells that it is to be forced.

have a look at these 2 links.

https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/335

https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/342